# A server git hook doesn't see a newly pushed code but the previous commit

Tags: git, hook

I have a git server hook "post-receive"

It's supposed to generate a special file out of the new code in a commit that's pushed. That file doesn't exist in the repo and is in .gitignore

**Each time I commit**, I need this file to be regenerated.

Issue: the special generated file sees the code 1 commit **behind** always. It seems so. As if the hook didn't have access to **the new code during a new push** and due to that the file is generated based on the previous, old commit.

And my question: is **the new code** that's being pushed actually visible to a server hook, in particular "post-receive" in the moment when a hook is being executed?

If yes, what can be the reason behind my issue?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR (but do read the rest): you want `git show $new:path/to/file.ext`.

Side note: Push-receiving repositories are normally bare ones (created with `git init --bare` or `git clone --bare`) and therefore have no work-tree.  You must be working with a non-bare repository.  Be sure you know what you are doing with this.

In either of the two "receive" hooks (pre-receive and post-receive), you are charged with reading *all* of the standard input.  What you will see on that input is a series of lines, of the form described in [the githooks documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html):

> ... for each ref to be updated it receives on standard input a line of the format:
>
> ```
> <old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
> ```
>
> where `<old-value>` is the old object name stored in the ref, `<new-value>` is the new object name to be stored in the ref and `<ref-name>` is the full name of the ref. When creating a new ref, `<old-value>` is 40 `0`.

(Not mentioned here, but important, is that when *deleting* a reference, the `<new-value>` is also 40 `0`s.)

When the kind-of-change is an update—i.e., neither the old nor the new hash values are all-zero—you can use `git rev-list` to find the commits, if any, that are (post-receive) or will be (pre-receive) newly introduced to the reference:

```
git rev-list $old..$new
```

Likewise, you can find which commits, if any, are being removed:

```
git rev-list $new..$old
```

These methods don't work for a newly-created reference, and of course a deletion means the reference won't exist at all, so both of these cases must be handled differently.

If you don't really care about either of these, though, you can simply inspect the file(s) you care about in the new value of the reference.  It's probably wise to check that the reference in question is the one that you care about, e.g., is `refs/heads/master` or is `refs/heads/deploy`, so that you don't do this for updates to references that *won't* be deployed (e.g., `refs/heads/work-in-progress`, or various tag references starting with `refs/tags/`).

To do this in a `--bare` repository, you could use `git show` to extract the file's content:

```
git show $new:path/to/file.ext | program_that_does_whatever
```

So, this means that your post-receive hook might read something like this (note, this is entirely untested):

```
#! /bin/sh
NULLHASH=$(git hash-object /dev/null | sed s/./0/g) # future-proofing

maybe_deploy() {
    local hash=$2 ref=$1
    case $ref in
    refs/heads/master)
        git show $hash:path/to/file.ext | deployment_program;;
    esac
}

while read old new ref; do
    case $old,$new in
    $NULLHASH,*) op=create;;
    *,$NULLHASH) op=delete;;
    *) op=update;;
    esac
    case $ref in
    refs/heads/*) reftype=branch;;
    refs/tags/*) reftype=tag;;
    *) reftype=other;;
    esac

    case $op,$reftype in
    update,branch|create,branch) maybe_deploy $ref $new;;
    # add other cases here if desired
    esac
done
```

This code is deliberately somewhat general, so that additional cases can be added as desired.